# How to insert column from another table when inserting it from userdefined datatable?

Tags: sql-server

```
    CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_InsertBulkShipmentData]
   (
     @RetVal                VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,
     @ship dbo.ShipmentData READONLY
   )

  AS

 DECLARE @ShipmentID            BIGINT
 Declare @Output table (id int)
 BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
dbo.Shipment (ShipmentType,scaccode,ShipmentControl,countryLoading,PortLoading,ShipperName,ShipperAddressOne,ShipperCity,ShipperCountry,ShipperProvince,
                    ShipperZip,ShipperPhone,ShipperEmail,ConsigneeName,ConsigneeAddressOne,ConsigneeCity,ConsigneeCountry,ConsigneeState,ConsigneeZip,
                    ConsigneePhone,ConsigneeEmail,ResponseCode,astrayExportDate,bondType,bondDestPort,bondOnwardscac,bondCarrierIRS,
                    bondNumber,bondTransferIRS,bondForeignPort,bondDepartureDate,MexiPediNumber)
                    OUTPUT Inserted.id into @Output
    SELECT sh.DDcode,s.SCACCode,s.ShipmentControl,s.CountryLoading,s.ProvinceLoading,s.ShipperName,s.ShipperAddress,s.ShipperCity,s.ShipperCountry,s.ShipperProvince,
             s.ShipperZip,s.ShipperPhone,s.ShipperEmail,s.ConsigneeName,s.ConsigneeAddressOne,s.ConsigneeCity,s.ConsigneeCountry,s.ConsigneeState,s.ConsigneeZip,
             s.ConsigneePhone,s.ConsigneeEmail,s.CustomControl,s.DateShipmentLeft,s.InbondEntryType,s.InbondDestination,s.OnwardCarrier,s.BondCarrier,
             s.Inbond,s.bondTransfer,s.ForeignPortDestination,s.EstimatedDeparture,s.MexiPediNumber
       FROM @ship s INNER JOIN ShipmentTypeDropDown sh on sh.DisplayName=s.ShipmentType

     
       select id from @Output 
SET @RetVal = 'true|Record Inserted Successfully|'
END
BEGIN

SELECT @ShipmentID=id;


INSERT INTO dbo.Ship_commodity([Description],Quantity,manifestUnitCode, 
[weight],weightUnitCode,countryCode,customsShipmentValue,commodityCode,MarksNumbers)                    

SELECT  sp.CommoditiesDescription,sp.Quantity,qu.DDCode,sp. 
[Weight],wu.DDCode,sp.CountryOrigin,sp.Value,sp.HarmonizedCode,sp.MarksNumbers
FROM @ship sp INNER JOIN WeightUnitDropDown wu on wu.DisplayName=sp.WeightUnitCode
INNER JOIN  QuantityUnitDropDown qu on qu.DisplayName=sp.QuantityUnit                                                           

END
```

id is autogenerated in Shipment table. I wan to insert this id into Ship_commodity where ShipmentID=id.
I am inserting the records from user defined datatable, for every record , id is generated in Shipment table. When inserting into
Ship_commodity table i want to insert the Shipment id for every record , where ShipmentID=id.
How should i achieve this? please suggest.

Comment: Join `@output`? What is `SELECT @ShipmentID=id;` meant to do, it doesn't make sense

Comment: I was trying to do something, I wanted to take id from shipment table for each record and insert into Ship_commodity as ShipmentID for those records , but i am inserting through userdefined table. so how can i achieve this?

Comment: What is the unique key on `@ship`, you will need to send that to `@output` also in order to join

Comment: SCACCode, ShipmentControl - the comibination of this is unique for every record. how to write that, what you are saying

Answer (score 1):

In your first `insert`, you need to get the primary key of `@ship` to be able to join the output table to it (make sure to add extra columns to `@output`):

```sql
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.scaccode, inserted.ShipmentControl into @Output
```

Then you can join `@output` to `@ship` (i'm assuming `Ship_commodity` has a column `fkShipmentId`):

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Ship_commodity
(fkShipmentId, [Description], Quantity, manifestUnitCode, [weight], weightUnitCode,
countryCode, customsShipmentValue, commodityCode, MarksNumbers)                    

SELECT
    i.id,
    sp.CommoditiesDescription,
    sp.Quantity,
    qu.DDCode,
    sp.[Weight],
    wu.DDCode,
    sp.CountryOrigin,
    sp.Value,
    sp.HarmonizedCode,
    sp.MarksNumbers
FROM @ship sp
INNER JOIN WeightUnitDropDown wu on wu.DisplayName=sp.WeightUnitCode
INNER JOIN QuantityUnitDropDown qu on qu.DisplayName=sp.QuantityUnit
INNER JOIN @output i ON i.scaccode = sp.scaccode AND i.ShipmentControl = sp.ShipmentControl;
```